# Generated *.SourceManifest doesn't include additional runCommand WebDeploy settings

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy, webdeploy-3.5

I'm trying to configure a `runCommand` to wait more than the default value of 1 second to finish.

This is a sample `pubxml` code:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
      <waitInterval>60000</waitInterval>
      <path>&quot;C:\Company\install-services.cmd&quot;</path>
    </MsDeploySourceManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I start a deployment, it successfully creates a `*.SourceManifest.xml` file in the temp package directory, but it only includes the path:

```
  <runCommand path="&quot;C:\Company\install-services.cmd&quot;" />
```

Furthermore, I'm deploying the whole web site from Visual Studio.

Is there any way to get more than the path parameter added to the resulting file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine except that `pubxml` item group requires an additional XML element. The final and working result looks like the following code:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
      <waitInterval>60000</waitInterval>
      <path>&quot;C:\Company\install-services.cmd&quot;</path>
      <AdditionalProviderSettings>waitInterval</AdditionalProviderSettings>
    </MsDeploySourceManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
```

My markup lacked the `<AdditionalProviderSettings>` element. Once I've added this element, the `*.SourceManifest.xml` generated by Visual Studio looked like this code:

```
...
<runCommand path="&quot;C:\Company\install-services.cmd&quot;" waitInterval="60000" />
...
```